# Web API: Multi thread when using Transaction (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 system which can communicate  through API each other.
Here is my code 
**System A:**

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    var myBook = _bookRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.bookID);
    myBook.AssigneeId = null;
    _bookRepository.Update(ticket);
    var result = await _anotherBApi.ApproveBookAsync(request.bookID);           
    if (result.ShStatus != ResponseStatus.Success)
    {
        result.ErrorType = ErrorType.Error;
        return result;
    }
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Function `ApproveBookAsync(request.bookID)` will call to **B system**'s API. After handling, **B system** call back **A system**'s API to update Book's information (the same the one above).

Above my code. I cannot `transaction.Complete();` because when B system call A system's API it will create new transaction.

**Expect:** I want to handle step by step as:

1. Update new information for a Book instance (sample ID = 1)
2. Call to B system's API (after B system also call A system's A to update Book ID = 1)
3. When call B system fail, I want to rollback all changes before. If success, commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using async/await in `TransactionScope` block, you need to opt that you need your transaction to flow accross thread continuations like this:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    // Your code that contains some calls to async method.
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Am I correct with that this won't work over different processes?